# Object creation differences

Tags: c++, object, allocation

What is the difference between the 2 following methods to create an object?

```
Test* t = new Test();
```

and

```
Test* t;
```

Your answers to second sample match with what i thought it would do (no object is created) But

```
class Test {
        public:
                void bla(void) {
                        std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
                };
};

int main(void) {
        Test* test;
        test->bla();
}
```

gives me the output "test"... So there is actually an Object

Comment: I fixed the formatting for you. The first edit's free ;-)

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `Test t` in that second snippet?

Comment: You mean the difference between creating an object and not creating an object?

Answer (score 7):

The first one does 4 things:

- create pointer to `Test`
- allocate memory and creates `Test` object (note, that it's `Test`, not `test` )
- the new object is value initialized, because of the `()` - see [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-newn) for more information
- initializes the pointer to point to the created object

The second one just creates pointer to `Test`. And it's not initialized.

---

@yogi - for your edit - this is totally **Undefined Behavior**, as the pointer is uninitialized. And no, it's *not* an object. See [C++ function called without object initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360501/c-function-called-without-object-initialization) for more information.

Comment: +1, you can also add that it in first case it's value initialized using `()` after `Test`.

Answer (score 4):

The second one doesn't create any object at all and trying to access it will result in Bad Things™.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pointer, allocated on the stack, and uses 32 or 64 bits of memory.

```
Test * t;
```

This will create an object of type Test on the heap (an you need to desalocate it)

```
t = new Test();
```

This will create an object of type Test on the stack (no need to desalocate it. It will disapear as soon as you exit the current context)

```
Test t2;
```

**Edit**

Your example works because the compiler optimized you code : it notices that you don't use any member, so it could doesn't make the effort you look for the instance.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is a method to create an instance of an object.

The second on is not a method to create an instance of an object. It merely declares a pointer, which remains uninitialised.

Answer (score 1):

After your update: The reason that it still successfully calls bla() is just undefined behaviour. Because that's exactly what the C++ Standard defines what is happening when you work with unsafe memory (in this case some arbitrary address that your pointer is pointing to) - the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Test* test;         
 test->bla();
```

As other answers have stated, `Test* test` does not create any object. It is a uninitialized pointer to `Test`. It is not pointing to anything valid unless it is initialized to point to a valid `Test` object.

Dereferencing an Uninitialized pointer like you are results in a ***Undefined Behaior***.
In your case it does not crash because you are not referring `this` inside `bla()`.
Nevertheless its still undefined behavior to dereference unitialized `test`.

To reiterate the above point, the following example will mostly crash.

```
#include<iostream>
class Test 
{
    public:
        int i; 
        void bla(void) 
        {
            std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "test->i" << this->i <<std::endl;
        }
};

int main(void) 
{
    Test* test;
    test->bla();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others already said, you're just lucky that the undefined behaviour that you trigger happens to look like what you thought you want (essentially because your Test::bla() is almost like a global free function). To see your example crash and burn, just add some non-trivial class members:

```
class Test {
public:
  void bla(void) {
    std::cout << "test: " << x << std::endl;
  };
  int x;
};
```

You can think of your original example as a free function

```
void bla(Test * p) { std::cout << "test" << std::endl; }
```

which you just happen to call with a garbage parameter, but since you don't use the parameter, nothing bad happens. In my modified example, we try to access `p->x` and die.